# I need a component to check state and rerender after another component changes (using React Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm not sure what I'm asking is even possible, but here goes. I have a web app with multiple components, two of which are a filterbar and a filter display. We had to do some major refactoring of the filterbar and change it from a class component to a functional component with hooks, and I had to include some forceUpdate code to get the filterbar to actually show the filter values that were chosen (i.e. clicking a filter selection on the filterbar would change the dashboard display, but wasn't changing the filterbar itself unless you closed and opened it again). The filter display component is a simple expansion panel that, by default, is open and shows the filters that are currently active. Previously, it would update automatically when a value in the filterbar changed, but since I rewrote the filterbar, it will only update if I close and reopen the expansion panel. Here's some of the code in filter display:

```
const FilterDisplay = props => {
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState("panel1");
const selectionFilters = useSelector(state => state.fetchFilter);
const availableFilters = useSelector(state => state.fetchFilterSelect);
const viz = useSelector(state => state.fetchDashboard);

const handleChange = panel => (event, isExpanded) => {
setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
};

return (
<div className={classes.rootPanel}>
  <MuiExpansionPanel
    expanded={expanded === "panel1"}
    onChange={handleChange("panel1")}
  >
    <MuiExpansionPanelSummary
      expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon edge="start" />}
    >
      <Typography variant="subtitle" className={classes.headingPanel}>
        Show Applied Filters
      </Typography>
    </MuiExpansionPanelSummary>

    {Object.keys(selectionFilters)
        .filter(key => {
          return (
            availableFilters[key] !== undefined &&
            availableFilters[key].length > 0 &&
            selectionFilters[key].length !==
            availableFilters[key].length 
          );
        })
        .map(title => {
          return (
            <MuiExpansionPanelDetails
              key={title}
              className={classes.ExpansionPanelD}
            >
              <Typography className={classes.filterTitle} variant="p">
                {title}
                {"  :  "}
              </Typography>

              {selectionFilters[title].length < 10 ? (
                selectionFilters[title].map(value => {
                  return (
                    <span key={value} className={classes.filterValue}>
                      <Chip
                        label={value}//this is the value that needs to change when the filterbar changes
                      />
                    </span>
                  );
                })
              ) : (
                  <Typography variant="p" className={classes.selection}>
                    {selectionFilters[title].length} selected
                  </Typography>
                )}
            </MuiExpansionPanelDetails>
          );
        })}
  </MuiExpansionPanel>
</div>
);
};

export default FilterDisplay;
```

I would code in a forceUpdate, but I can't figure out how to do it without causing unlimited rerenders (unlike the Filterbar, where I want it to change when the user specifically does something on the filterbar, i need the filter display to update, not when someone opens or closes the filter display, but when they change something on the filterbar). Can anyone give me some ideas? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using `useSelector()` from react-redux to obtain your selectionFilters. From the [docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates):

> When the function component renders, the provided selector function will be called and its result will be returned from the useSelector() hook. [...] useSelector() only forces a re-render if the selector result appears to be different than the last result. As of v7.1.0-alpha.5, **the default comparison is a strict === reference comparison**.

`useSelector()` receives as second argument a callback in which you can perform the comparison yourself. In the docs they recomend using shallowEqual which they export in react-redux:

```
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
// ...

const selectionFilters = useSelector(state => state.fetchFilter, shallowEqual);
```

You can of course provide the comparison function yourself it this doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Kevin! I added shallowEqual as noted above, but it doesn't appear to have changed anything. Do I need to do anything different in the way I've written the HTML section?

Comment: You shouldn't need to (it's jsx btw). If shallowEqual does not cut it you can always write an `areSelectionFiltersEqual(prev, now)` function and pass it as second parameter. It seems that your data is shaped like `{titleA: ['valuea', 'valueb'], titleB: ['valuec', 'valued']}` so you might want to compare not only the object keys and values but also the arrays values. Or you might want to use a deep comparison function from a library, like lodash's [_.isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual)

Comment: Thank you, Kevin! I think I found a solution, I'll post it below; it doesn't work exactly as before, but I think it makes sense from a user perspective. I'll try playing around with your suggestion and see if I can make my code a little more elegant. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution that doesn't make it re-render as soon as the filterbar changes, but it does cause a re-render when the filterbar closes. Basically, right after the handleChange function, I added this little code block:

```
if (props.drawerOpen) {
console.log(props.selectionFilters)
};
```

So basically, a user will open the filterbar, make changes, close the filterbar, and the filter display will update with the changes.